# Django save form with m2m field

Tags: django

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
this is model

```
class Package(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(u'Ид', primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid1)
    region_code = models.IntegerField(u'Код региона', default=APP_REGION_CODE[:2], help_text='PackageUUID')
    persons = models.ManyToManyField(Person, verbose_name=u'Персоны', null=True, related_name='packages')
```

model Person is simple name surname and primary key auto field

```
class PackageForm(ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Package
        fields = ('id', 'region_code', 'persons')
        widgets = {
            'id': widgets.TextInput(attrs={'size': 30}),
            'persons': widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'size': 30})
                   }
    def clean_persons(self):
        persons = self.cleaned_data.get('persons')
        for person in persons:
        in_db, created = InfoBlock.objects.update_or_create(person=person)
```

this is part of the view that process form

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = PackageForm(request.POST)
    
    # проверяем коррекность введенных данных и сохраняем. Связанные модели будут привязаны к пакету
    if form.is_valid:
        form.save()
        messages.append(u'Операция прошла успешно!')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('list'))
        
   
else:
    form = PackageForm()

form.fields['persons'].queryset = Person.objects.all()
```

in debugger I get after post request
`request.POST['persons'] = u'1933'`
but `form.cleaned_data`

```
{
  'id': UUID('3102af8c-7614-11eb-ad4a-107b4493a520'),
  'persons': None,
  'region_code': 66
}
```

why form don't set persons field from POST data?

Comment: Why do you set `form.fields['persons'].queryset = Person.objects.all()`?

Comment: sorry i don't include filter form.fields['persons'].queryset = Person.objects.filter(surname='Smith'). In form.data I see value u'1747' but in cleaned_data there is no data (None value)

Comment: I add to forms full clean ( before i use clean_persons method in form class)     def clean(self):
        super(PackageForm, self).clean()
        persons = self.cleaned_data.get('persons')
        for person in persons:
            in_db, created = InfoBlock.objects.update_or_create(person=person) and it works fine

Comment: please [edit] the question.